# Long execution time with BETWEEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Execution time for this query is more then 2 seconds (for 10k rows). Is it possible to optimize this query?

```
SELECT id, MIN(ABS(timestamp_a - timestamp_b))
FROM a 
  INNER JOIN b ON ( timestamp_a  between (timestamp_b - 5 * 60) 
              AND (timestmap_b + 5 * 60) )
GROUP BY id
```

Sample result (id, timestamp_a, timestamp_b, diff):

```
1   1349878538  1349878539  1
2   1349878679  1349878539  2
3   1349878724  1349878539  1
5   1349878836  1349878539  1
6   1349878890  1349878641  1
```

Table a

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
`id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`timestamp_a`  bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `a` (`timestamp_a`) USING BTREE 
)
```

Table b

```
CREATE TABLE `b` (
`id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`timestamp_b`  bigint(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `b` (`timestamp_b`) USING BTREE 
)
```

Both table is not related between - I search for records from table 'a' which are between timestamp in table 'b'.

**EDIT: simples solution (run very fast):**

```
SELECT id, MIN(ABS(timestamp_a - timestamp_b))
FROM (SELECT id, timestamp, (timestamp - 5 * 60) timestamp_a, (timestamp + 5 * 60) timestamp_b) a
INNER JOIN b ON ( timestamp between timestamp_a AND timestamp_b )
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: can you explain your table structure better? Possible include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for both tables in your question. How do the tables relate to each other? I think the main issue is your very complex JOIN condition, but it is hard to recommend alternative without this info.

Comment: thx for your answer - please see my question now

Comment: It won't help significantly with this query, but you should make the timestamp columns either `TIMESTAMP`s or `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`; `BIGINT` is just the wrong type.  The ID columns should also be `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: BIGINT because it is microtime.

Comment: If speed is more important that normalization... you could add two columns to table `b`: `timestamp_b_minus` and `timestamp_b_plus`... these two columns would contain the results of the calculation that you're performing in your join.  You could then index these two columns, which would prevent the table scanning that you're likely seeing now.

Comment: @Michael In my case it is not possible to add those columns, but your suggestion can help.

Comment: @ekstro Fair enough about the timestamps being `BIGINT`s, but they should still be `UNSIGNED`.  It's minor, but correct.

Comment: @G-Nugget right, my fault - thx!

Comment: I have a feeling that it's being slowed down by the calculation. Try to move the calculation into a sub-query.

Comment: I edited my post with simplest solution for this. Now it run very fast. What do you think about this?

Comment: The `timestamp_b +/- 300` requires MySQL to perform the calculation for each row, thus ignoring the index. Either add 2 columns (as said Michael) or you could create a `b` temp table with the 2 results if either `b` has less rows (for a significant difference) than `a` or if you repeat the query with the same `b` data.

Answer (score 0):

Taking Michael's conventions for the modified timestamp columns, this query will produce the intended results of the original query with the performance of the "faster" query above:

```
SELECT a.id, MIN(ABS(a.timestamp_a - tmp_b.timestamp_b))
FROM (SELECT id, timestamp_b, (timestamp_b - 5 * 60) timestamp_b_minus, (timestamp_b + 5 * 60) timestamp_b_plus) tmp_b
INNER JOIN a ON ( a.timestamp_a between tmp_b.timestamp_b_minus AND tmp_b.timestamp_b_plus )
GROUP BY a.id
```

The reason that the original query is experience performance constraints is that the RDBMS is forced to perform a full table scan of `b` for every row in `a` due to the formula used in the ON clause.

Even though the "faster" query requires a full table scan of `b` to generate the "temporarily" table `tmp_b` it is able to use the index on `a.timestamp_a` to extract the appropriate values from `a` based on the criteria: **tmp_b.timestamp_b_minus AND tmp_b.timestamp_b_plus**